# Delete record in patchentities in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

Some rows which are related to employee are needed to be updated
User can update some record and delete some record in same form.

while doing patch entity list of records which is already present in table are fetched and stored in list object and it is patched with data which comes by request.
But only records are updated not deleted while doing patch entity.

```
$UserSkillsTable = \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('UserSkills');

$list = $this->UserSkills
    ->find('ALL')
    ->contain(['MsSkills', 'MsSkills.MsSkillHeads', 'SkillLevels', 'RoSkillLevels'])
    ->where([
        'UserSkills.emp_code' => $this->request->session()->read('user_emp_code'),
        'approve_status' => 'P',
        'UserSkills.is_active' => '1'
    ])
    ->toArray();

$userSkillEntities = $this->UserSkills->patchEntities(
    $list,
    $this->request->data['old_user_skill']
);
```

Comment: This question requires clarification, what are you actually asking?

Comment: How to delete record from associated table in patch entity @david yell

Comment: `patchEntity` only deals with entities, hence the name, it does not persist data to a datastore. It's also not possible to use this method to delete data from an entity. It's mostly used to merge data into an entity.

Comment: what to do to solve this kind to problem where we are required to update associated tables which include both modification of existing records or deletion of them in that table using cakephp 3 ORM .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294313/deleting-records-from-associated-table-with-patchentity-in-cakephp